# Get database schema with one query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-schema

Basically I want to get the table names, and the field names for each table from the current database that is connected, nothing else.

Is this possible?

I know that `SHOW TABLES FROM my_database` gets you the table names, and `SHOW COLUMNS FROM my_table` will get you the fields, but that's at least [1 x # of tables] queries and I get more information that I want :)

Comment: Does it need to be in PHP or can you use [mysql dump](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/mysql/dump-just-the-table-structure-to-a-file-in-mysql/)?

Comment: within php (I'm using PDO to do queries)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html) table has what you're asking for.

```
SELECT table_name, column_name
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_schema = 'YourDBName'
    ORDER BY table_name, ordinal_position
```

Comment: I get info from all the databases

Comment: @Alex: I added a where clause for you.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables t
JOIN information_schema.columns c ON t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME 
 AND t.TABLE_CATALOG=c.TABLE_CATALOG 
 AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA=c.TABLE_SCHEMA
```

works for SQLSERVER 2005.  The column names might be different for MySQL (I assume that's what you're using), but the concept is the same.

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL both use information_schema structure that is reasonably similar to standard SQL, but FWIW MySQL doesn't support catalogs, so table_catalog is always the literal string `'def'`.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT t.name AS tblName,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS [schemaName],
c.name AS colName
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
ORDER BY tblName;
```

Answer (score 1):

"Show databases", "Show tables" and "describe table" are the best, fastest way I know of in MySql.

But they *are* MySql-specific.

If you want:

a) a portable way to query your database schema

```
 ... AND ...
```

b) more granular control over your query, then look at INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

SYNTAX:

```
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE table_schema = 'db_name'
  [AND table_name LIKE 'wild']
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few trials, i made this sql code to see the columns in my table.

```
SELECT 
TABLE_NAME as table_name, 
COLUMN_NAME as column_name, 
COLUMN_TYPE as data_type, 
COLUMN_DEFAULT as default_value, 
IS_NULLABLE as nullable,
COLUMN_KEY as constraints, 
EXTRA as constraints2, 
CHARACTER_SET_NAME as charset, 
COLLATION_NAME as collation 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_schema = '<YOUR_DATABASE_NAME>' 
AND TABLE_NAME='<YOUR_TABLE_NAME>' 
ORDER BY table_name, ordinal_position
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the following stored procedure and make sure to replace 'your_database_name' in the two locations before saving the procedure.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE SummarizeTables()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE tableName CHAR(255);
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT table_name 
        FROM information_schema.tables 
        WHERE table_schema = 'your_database_name'; -- specify your database name here

    -- Handlers
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    -- A temporary table for storing the summary
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TableSummary;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TableSummary (
        TableName CHAR(255),
        ColumnName CHAR(255),
        DataType CHAR(255),
        IsNullable CHAR(10),
        ColumnKey CHAR(10)
    );

    OPEN cur;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO tableName;

        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        -- Dynamic SQL to insert table details into the summary table
        SET @s = CONCAT("INSERT INTO TableSummary (TableName, ColumnName, DataType, IsNullable, ColumnKey) 
                        SELECT '", tableName, "', COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_KEY 
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name' AND TABLE_NAME = '", tableName, "'");

        PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur;

    -- Now select the data from the summary table
    SELECT * FROM TableSummary;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Then run the following sql query:

```
CALL SummarizeTables();
```

This will generate a summary table of your schema.